# Defining class inside class and declaring the same class in another translation unit causes ambiguity?

Tags: c++, class

Suppose I have the following code.

```cpp
class External
{
public:
    struct Internal
    {
        //definition
    }

    //whatever

}
```

And I also have declared `struct Internal` in another translation unit, such as

```
.
.
.
struct Internal;
.
.
.
```

My question is, may this cause some sort of ambiguity? And if not, how can I separate the definition and declaration of `External::Internal` into `.h` and `.cpp` files?

Comment: they're different `struct Internal`

Comment: `External::Internal` and `::Internal` are two different unrelated things. To define `External::Internal` outside of `External`, just define it: `struct External::Internal { ... };`